# mongoexport with parameters + node.js + child process

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, csv

I am trying to export a csv using node.js from mongodb. For this i started with this code:

```
app.get('/export', function(req, res) {
 var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
 ls = spawn('mongoexport');
res.sendfile('/home/database.csv'); 
});
```

And this works fine. Then for making it more usable i tried to code below with mongoexport using arguments:

```
 app.get('/export', function(req, res) {
 var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
 ls = spawn('mongoexport --db lms --collection databases --fields firstname,lastname,email,daytimePhone,addressOne,city,state,postalCode,areaOfStudy,currentEducationLevel,company --csv --out /home/database.csv');
res.sendfile('/home/database.csv') 

});
```

This throws a exception:

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: spawn ENOENT
    at errnoException (child_process.js:980:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:771:34)
```

Then i tried using only one argument but it gives the same error :(

I tried this also to see if arguments work this way but the same error:

```
spawn('mongoexport',['--csv']);
```

Answer (score 5):

The syntax for spawn is:

```
spawn(<command>, [array of arguments]);
```

For example, doing a `ls` command with `-l /home` options would look like this:

```
ls = spawn('ls', ['-l', '/home'];
```

So your `spawn('mongoexport',['--csv']);` is heading in the right direction but `mongoexport --csv` is not valid.  That's why you're getting error.  mongoexport needs more than just `--csv`. Like what you've done above, you, for instance, need to specify database name (`-d "lms"`), collection name (`-c "databases"`), field names (`--fields firstname,lastname`), and etc.

In your case, it should be something like this:

```
 var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
 app.get('/export', function(req, res) {
     var mongoExport = spawn('mongoexport', [ 
         '--db', 'lms', '--collection', 'databases', 
         '--fields',
         'firstname,lastname,email,daytimePhone,addressOne,city,state,postalCode,areaOfStudy,currentEducationLevel,company',   
         '--csv'
     ]);

     res.set('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
     mongoExport.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
         if (data) {
             // You can change or add something else here to the
             // reponse if you like before returning it.  Count
             // number of entries returned by mongoexport for example
             res.send(data.toString());
         } else {
             res.send('mongoexport returns no data');
         }
     });
}
```

Comment: ok the csv gets generated correctly...but i guess this line gets executed before the generation has finished:  res.sendfile('/home/database.csv'). Any callback for this?

Comment: This just gives me a download of a file called "export" with no parameters applied :(

Comment: beNerd, I currently don't have the environment to test the code you have above and see what it's doing in the debugger.  I'll do that when I have some cycle.  In the mean time, try setting Content-Type before calling res.senfile().  Something like this:  res.set('Content-Type', 'text/plain');

Comment: @beNerd, as robertklep said, creating /home/database.csv would introduce race condition.  So avoid it is good.  One way is to pipe the output to res like robertklep suggested.  Another way is to add event handler to 'data' event.  This approach allows you to add something before after the output in the response.  You can event do something like altering the result, count number of entries and etc.  Since robertklep already put down the pipe solution.  I'll modify my answer to handle 'data' event.

Comment: this goes in the non-terminating condition and nginx timesout!

Comment: Hmm, I tested locally on my mac and it works. It looks like it's not getting into the 'data' event handler on nginx... have to do some research and see if I can find anything...

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a race condition, where `/home/database.csv` could get truncated/overwritten by multiple requests for `/export` that come in (almost) simultaneously.

Using the code that Ben provided, I would pipe the output of `mongoexport` directly to the response object, thus not needing to use a temporary file:

```
app.get('/export', function(req, res) {
  // Set correct content-type
  res.set('Content-Type', 'text/csv');
  // Export collection and pipe to `res`
  spawn('mongoexport', [ 
    '--db', 'lms', '--collection', 'databases', 
    '--fields', 'firstname,lastname,email,daytimePhone,addressOne,city,state,postalCode,areaOfStudy,currentEducationLevel,company', 
    '--csv'
  ]).stdout.pipe(res);
});
```

Personally I would generate the CSV directly from Node using a MongoDB driver and [`csv`](https://npmjs.org/package/csv).

Comment: may i know why i should not take this approach and generate the csv directly as suggested by you?

Comment: @beNerd I'm not suggesting you *shouldn't*, just that I probably wouldn't do it myself :) (spawning new processes for a request takes quite some resources, but if it's not being called that often that probably doesn't matter)

Comment: i tried the method of ben but it just gives me a download of a file called "export" with no parameters applied :(

Comment: @beNerd start with a simple script first, see [this gist](https://gist.github.com/robertklep/7046bef559b5dadcab86). See what that does.

Comment: it just says "connected to 127.0.0.1" in the terminal and nothing else