# "Error: spawn mongoexport ENOENT" when running dockerized node app

Tags: node.js, linux, mongodb, docker

I am in the process of dockerizing one of our node application. One of the features of this application is, at the start, the app downloads mongodb data using mongoexport and write into a file.

I am doing this using child_process spawn

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var mongoExport = spawn('mongoexport', [
                 '--db', 'dbname', '--collection', 'collection1',
                 '--fields',
                 'name,address,city,country,pincode',
                 '--type', 'csv'
             ]);
```

The app starts and works fine when i run 'node app.js' from command prompt.

However, when I dockerized this node app, and try to run I get "*Error: spawn mongoexport ENOENT*".

I run mongodb in one container, and node app in another container linking with mongodb container

> docker run --restart=always --name mongo-rnd -v
>   /opt/mongo_rnd:/data/db -d mongo:3.2.7
>
> docker run -e "MONGO_HOST=mongo-rnd" -p 8081:8081 -d --name nodeapp --link mongo-rnd:mongo-rnd nodeappimageid

I have tried the following to debug this issue,

1. I checked by commenting out mongoexport feature, everything works fine as expected.
2. I thought, it could be an issue with child_process inside the docker container. So, I tried with a simple 'ls' command

> ```
> const ls = spawn('ls', ['-lh', '/usr']);
> ls.stdout.on('data', function(data){
>   console.log("stdout:" + data);
> });
> ```

No issue, it worked fine.

so, my conclusion is the command 'mongoexport' is not available inside the nodejs docker container.

Anyone have idea how to achieve this ? or isn't it possible to do this ?

Here is my docker file for reference

```
FROM node:wheezy

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/temp

COPY . /usr/src/temp

WORKDIR /usr/src/temp
RUN npm install

ENV PORT=8081
ENV MONGO_HOST "localhost"

EXPOSE 8081
CMD node app.js
```

Comment: Could it be that `--type` is redundant and `--csv` alone suffices? Seen in [mongoexport with parameters + node.js + child process](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20176549/1983854). Although [I see](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/) from mongoexport 3.0.0 `--type=csv` is the correct way.

Comment: yes. you are correct. --type is not recognized in latest mongo (I was testing with 3.2.7). its enough to specify as --csv

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I have rightly guessed, the issue is that 'mongodb' was not installed in the nodeapp container.

All I had to do was add the following lines in the Dockerfile to install mongodb in nodeapp container

```
RUN apt-get update 
RUN apt-get install -y mongodb
```

From the code I had to specify `--host` and `--port` in mongoexport call:

```
var mongoExport = spawn('mongoexport', [
                 '--db', 'dbname', '--host', 'mongo-rnd', '--port', 27017, '--collection', 'collection1','--fields', 'name,address,city,country,pincode',
                 '--csv']);
```